# Symfony including assets (stylesheets/js) based on the controller

Tags: javascript, css, symfony

I am trying to find a good way to make my js and css modulo. The thought came to me that when a particular controller is run, it would automatically find a corresponding css/js file and add it. E.g. if i run the TodoController, then a TodoController.css file will be automatically loaded.

Has anyone done something like this?
If its not really the way to go, then how would one load the assets needed per controller?

Comment: Can you, please, explain why would you like to load assets based on controller?

Comment: So i dont need to load all css that i dont need. If im on a todo list i dont need the css for a profile for example. How would you do it? All in one file?

Answer (score 0):

The right approach would be loading assets based on the views, resp. logical areas of your project and not on the controllers.
The Twig templating system has a powerful inheritance ability, so you can define base templates for specific areas of your project (with specific assets) and then extend these with templates for particular views (a.k.a. pages).

You can learn more on this here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#template-inheritance